# How to do groupBy and add the sum of the values grouped in underscore.js

Tags: react-native, underscore.js

From this:

```
var x = [ 
    {category: 'Title', price: 100 }, 
    {category: 'Title', price: 200 },
    {category: 'Title3', price: 300 },
    {category: 'Title3', price: 400 },
    {category: 'Title5', price: 500 },
];
```

To this:

```
var x = [
    {category: 'Title', price: 300},
    {category: 'Title3', price: 700},
    {category: 'Title5', price: 500},
];
```

The logic is same as SQL query:

```
SELECT category, sum (price) FROM x GROUP BY category;
```

Comment: I changed the SQL to fit the GROUP BY structure in the title and example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Updated:

1. `groupBy` will group the initial array by "category".
2. `map` will then iterate each object in the grouped array by passing in two params: `key` and `value`. The first `key` will be "Title" and its `value` is an array of `[{category: 'Title', price: 100 }, {category: 'Title', price: 200 }]`.
3. Before returning an updated array in `map`, `reduce` is used to sum up the "price". Basically, it iterates through the array (first param) and return the sum from the function (second param). Note that in the first iteration, the `total` will be `0` (last param in `reduce`). So, the first return will be `0 + 100` which is then passed in as 'new' `total` in the second iteration and so on.

You can refer to the [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/) for more details.

Try this:

```
var groups = _.groupBy(x, 'category');
var result = _.map(groups, function(value, key) {
  return { 
    category: key, 
    price: _.reduce(value, function(total, o) { 
        return total + o.price;
    }, 0) 
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works for me but can you explain how mapping and reducing works. I'm new to underscore.js and trying to figure out how things work.

Comment: @TheChosenOne Updated my answer with some explanations. Hope, it helps.